# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum save photo from camera to late

Tags: ios, swift

how to get url on photo taken from camera? photo save after closing dialog.
permisions:

- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
- Privacy - Camera Usage Description

image controller

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage!, self, nil, nil)

    guard let document = getDocument(from: info) else {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    viewModel?.documens.append(document)
    documentsCollectionView.reloadData()
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func getDocument(from imageInfo: [String: Any]) -> DocumentRepresentable? {
    guard let selectedImage = imageInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage,
        let imageURL = imageInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL else {
            return nil
    }
    return Document(path: imageURL.path, data: selectedImage)
}
```

open camera func

```
  private func showCameraPicker() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
            myPickerController.delegate = self

            viewModel?.context?.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the _problem_ that you are facing ?

Comment: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum save the photo after closing the dialog box. Therefore photo url = nil